I am trying to setup VPN on a server running Windows Server 2022. Why can't I connect as a client from Windows 11?
I am trying to setup VPN on a server running Windows Server 2022. I cannot connect as a client from Windows 11. The current error is RasClient 789. The RAS manager on the server says that everything is just fine.
This article was my primary source:

https://hostadvice.com/how-to/web-hosting/windows/how-to-set-up-a-vpn-server-on-windows-server-2022/

I am using L2TP for which both client and server are configured.
The server also runs Hyper-V. I have 2 physical nics if that helps for a solution but only 1 active and configured. I used both vEthernet adapter and its dependency on nic1 as the NAT interface in RRA but neither allows the client to connect.
I have tried numerous client and server side techniques to resolve connectivity. The client references one of the 2 IP addresses I configured for RRA properties. I have also tried using just the host IP address which is unpingable, but the 2 IP addresses I configured are pingable so I went with them. My HSP provides the IP addresses. But I thought VPN assigned the IP addresses from the specified pool and that I should connect to the server IP. And yes I know that there are various reasons why a live server could not be pingable.
On the other hand, maybe I should be using virtual addresses like 192.168.0.0/16 rather than the IP addresses supplied by my HSP (that is my next experiment).
It took a lot of effort to get internet connectivity on the host physical machine but that did not help. I have internet connectivity on each of the VMs (although that should be completely irrelevant).
I am looking for direction on what to untangle especially since I am not certain whether the problem is client or server. I have deleted the network adapters on the client and recreated, changed registry settings, made sure that CHAPS v2 is used, turned off firewalls, etc, etc…
The VPN access is to allow remote administration of the server since my HSP is telling me to use raw RDP for which I want to burn that company to the ground. So after I configure VPN, I will try RDP or hopefully direct access. This is my first foray into VPN.

Problem solved.
I used a variant of 192.168.0.0/16 and connected in a split second. So trying to use the HSP-supplied hard IP addresses was the huge mistake.
I simply went to RRAS server properties -> click IP4 tab -> add the synthetic IP addresses and restarted RRAS. Now on to figuring out how to use VPN. The client connects to the server ip as I had figured. And I am using physical nic - not the v-nic.
A whole day went up in flames, but at least I can sleep tonight and get my HSP off my back about IPMI.
